# Install MongoDB PHP Extension for PHP 8.1 (Debian)

Tags: php, mongodb, debian, pecl

sorry if there is a duplicate question for this but I'm trying to set this up for hours now and it just doesn't work.

I have a Debian 11 server with "KeyHelp" installed on it (little brother of plesk). It comes with PHP 7.4 but provides a simple Dashboard where you can install other PHP versions. I installed PHP 8.1 and tried to install the mongodb extension via PECL.

After "pecl install mongodb" I added "extension=mongodb.so" and after that didn't show up the extension on the phpinfo page, I double checked if the extension is really in the extension folder of php, where it was.

**Turns out that I installed the extension for PHP 7.4 and not for PHP 8.1. Finally I tried to force PECL to install it for PHP 8.1 but it says "phpize8.1 command not found". I found no way to install phpize8.1, can somebody help me out with that?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 
I have PHP 8.1 version. You have to install modules of PHP

**sudo apt install php8.1-mongodb**

List the modules

**php -m**


It's not exactly Debian. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you run command:

```
sudo apt install php-dev
```

System will install automatically the correct version of `php{x}-dev` for your distribution, and all it's dependencies, included PECL.

another way is try to run:

```
/usr/bin/phpize
```

If this command works, you need to add phpize to your PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH\:/usr/bin; export PATH
```

In this way phpize will work in future.

Comment: Thanks for your help! When i try "apt install php-dev" it says that it's already installed. I did this before and I guess it installed the php-dev for php 7.4 as it was the default php version before I installed php 8.1 later on.

/usr/bin/phpize works and I added it to the PATH. When I try to use pecl install for php 8.1 then it says again "phpize8.1: not found"

Comment: You can try to run `sudo apt install php8.1-dev`, then check if all runs. Let me know.

Comment: I tried that already too… in php7.4 its installed perfectly tho

Comment: But you have enabled php8 and disable then 7? ```$ sudo a2dismod php7.4
$ sudo a2enmod php8.1
$ sudo service apache2 restart``` or in command line ```sudo update-alternatives --set php /user/bin/php8.1 && update-alternatives --set phar /user/bin/phar8.1 && update-alternatives --set phar.phar /user/bin/phar.phar8.1```?